# x86 assembly: Having hard time finding a good and short algorithm which can encrypt and decrypt hex values

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in x86 assembly which can encrypt a given hex value and then decrypt it in less then 20 to 30 lines, But to no avail.

I haven't really found any sort of algorithm which does such thing and in assembly as well, hopefully anyone of you guys have an idea or an algorithm that I can use.

I thought about decrypting each letter individually, but the only real encryption that I know that I might be able to implement is Caesar Cipher. But it's way to easy to decrypt for the thing I'm going to do.

I'm using the emu8086 emulator for this.

Comment: So you want a symmetric cipher, where the same key encrypts and decrypts?  (i.e. the kind of crypto you'd use after establishing a shared key using Diffie-Helman key exchange, or public-key crypto like RSA).  Obviously if you're designing it yourself you don't expect it to be actually secure, just non-trivial for an amateur to break by hand.  What kind of key size do you want to use?  Obviously XOR with a very long key (same length as message) is easy, and is actually the only provably perfectly secure algo (one time pad).

Comment: A sequence of shift and rotate, and XOR, can be a good compromise, like the now-obsolete DES.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard.  A simplified and maybe smaller version of that (e.g. using 32-bit chunks so you can rotate with only a pair of `adc ax,ax` / `adc dx,dx` instructions) might work ok.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh I think that I've heard about that xor encryption. But I couldn't find any good implementation for it in 8086 assembly... I'll check your link in a sec. Thank you :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad is what you get for *purely* using just XOR, with a key of the same length as the message.  Reusing a short key for every word or dword of a message is pretty terrible, the modern digital equivalent of Caesar.

Comment: @PeterCordes And if I want the message to be decryptable, I just need to use a key which doesn't change each time, then use xor with that? Also, do you have any implementation of such thing which I can use to learn from?

Comment: The “one-time” part of “one-time pad” means that you can’t reuse the key for another message.

Comment: @Kidsm: `lodsw` / `xor [di], ax` / `add di,2` in a loop XORs one array into another.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I get it. I'll try it now. Thank you!

Comment: @prl: Oh, just remembered, a good strategy is to use a PRNG as a source for the stream of data to XOR with.  That's how [Stream Ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) like RC4 / RC5 work.  You can use a simple cipher that isn't *cryptographically secure* and it will do quite well for toy use, e.g. [XORshift+](http://prng.di.unimi.it/) as a PRNG, and use the bytes from that as your XOR cipher stream instead of a one-time pad.  The seed for your RNG is your encryption key.  A compact xorshift32+ should be possible with a couple registers on 16-bit 8086.

Comment: @PeterCordes ehmm just to clarify, you suggest to take the original message, then do xorshift, and then use it as my key for the encrypting itself? If so I just need to understand how to do that xorshift thingy Dx

Comment: No, you need a secret key separately, that you use to seed a PRNG to give you a stream of random bytes, 2 or 4 at a time.  It can be hard-coded into your program, or a separate input.

Comment: ohh So I need to choose a key, then do the xorshifting on it, and then use it as my key on the xor encryption? I think I got you. The only problem is to make that xorshift thing, which is still mysterious for me 0.0

Comment: That's why I linked to a site with implementations in various languages.

Comment: Updated my answer with TEA, the Tiny Encryption Algorithm.  It's a "real" modern crypto algo intended to be secure in the modern era.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want a symmetric cipher, where the same key is needed to encrypt and decrypt? (i.e. the kind of crypto you'd use after establishing a shared key using Diffie-Hellman key exchange, or public-key crypto like RSA, or by some pre-existing secret side channel).

Obviously if you're designing it yourself you **[don't expect it to be actually secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=do%20not%20roll%20own)**, just hopefully non-trivial for an amateur to break by hand if you get it right and the application/protocol that uses it doesn't screw it up (e.g. leak the key, reuse keys insecurely, or generate weak keys).  Real digital cryptography is *hard*; there's a reason the world spent years evaluating ciphers before standardizing on Rijndael as the winner to [become AES in 2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), and why it's so complicated and works in chunks of 128 bits.  And using it to encrypt/decrypt longer messages requires choosing one of various techniques to apply that block cipher without just repeating exactly the same operation on each 128-bit chunk separately, e.g. cipher-block chaining.  (Then an attacker could tell if the plaintext had two 128-bit chunks that were identical or not.)

---

**The simplest approach is to XOR the plaintext with some key.**  Doing that again will decrypt because that's how XOR works.

If you repeat the same short key for every byte or word of the message, that's the digital equivalent of a Caesar cipher; pretty easy for even amateurs to break.

If you have a secret key that's as long as the message, then this is a "[one time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)".  (Unless you use the same key with different plaintexts, then you've defeated the security because an attacker can XOR the two ciphertexts together to cancel the key, and have the XOR of two plaintexts.  A chosen-plaintext attack would totally defeat this.)  But if you do never reuse a truly random key, then this is the only cryptography that's *provably* secure.  Of course it's not very useful because you need the sender and receiver to already have enough shared-secret data.  Useful if you're sending a spy out into the field with one copy of a codebook, not useful for separate computers running indefinitely.

So simple XOR with a giant key is perfect if you never reuse keys, but much weaker than more complex encryption if you want to reuse a key or have a short key.

---

**A good strategy might be to use a PRNG to expand a small key into an arbitrary-length stream of bytes which you XOR the message with**.  i.e. the key is a seed for a random number generator.  (And is a separate input to the program, or one specific key could be hard-coded into a toy program.)

That's how [Stream Ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) like RC4 / RC5 work, i.e. they're CSPRNGs: Cryptographically-Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generators.

Just like one-time pads, they are totally defeated by reusing the same key, if the attacker knows this is happening.  But obviously if you're designing your own cipher you shouldn't have *any* expectation of real security.  Still, hard-coding a key into your program would be worse for this strategy compared to other ways of doing some mixing.

For this toy program, you can use a simple PRNG that isn't cryptographically secure, e.g. [XORshift+](http://prng.di.unimi.it/).  A compact xorshift32+ should be possible with a couple registers on 16-bit 8086.  The main site I linked only has 128 and 256-bit state versions, but does mention xorshift32+ on a 16-bit CPU.

However, any old simple [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) might be ok for your use, maybe even a simple [LCG as a multiply / add with a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), with modulo being an implicit modulo by 2^16 by only taking the 16-bit result in AX.  That's only a couple instructions.  If you cared about performance on a real 8086 you'd avoid multiply (because it's slow).

---

**The other major strategy** to consider is a sequence of rotate, XOR, and ADD, like the now-obsolete DES. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard.  (And maybe shift, but rotate and XOR are easily reversible because they don't destroy information.)

A simplified and maybe smaller version of that (e.g. using 32-bit chunks so you can rotate by one with only a pair of `adc ax,ax` / `adc dx,dx` instructions) might work ok.

**There is a Tiny Encryption Algorithm** ([wikipedia has a C version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)) which is based on Feistel rounds (shift two ways, add magic constants, xor together), and is intended to be cheap + simple to implement, although some weaknesses have been found in it.  (Although it does have 128-bit keys and a 64-bit block-size.)  Broken attempt at a 32-bit x86 asm implementation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338505/the-values-of-operands-in-tea-algorithm-will-not-get-decrypted-correctly-in-asse).

Shifting by 4 or 5 on 8086 is not cheap (need a count in CL, unless you can abuse `AAA` or something to split 4-bit nibbles with something cheaper than `aam 16` which will do hardware division and is even slower).  Doing far fewer than the suggested 64 rounds per block would help performance but not necessarily code-size, if you don't care about the full security.

**Encrypting different messages with the same key should be less trivial for amateurs to break with a cipher of this kind of design than a stream cipher.**  And possibly even non-trivial for experience cryptographers.

You could still evolve the key every step using a PRNG like xorshift+ or something even simpler, so the same 4 letters don't encrypt the same way every time if they happen to be aligned.  Or if you don't care about that and need the code-size to stay small, maybe you give up on that.  Or just increment the key every step, or do [cipher block chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) where you XOR the plaintext for a new block with the previous ciphertext.  That's just one section of a Wiki article about various ways to use block cipher algos on a large stream of data.

Decrypt and encrypt are not the same function with this strategy; you need to do things in reverse order.

Comment: @Kidsm In case you are not aware: on Cryptography.SE there is a golden rule that the professionals try hard to communicate to amateurs (software engineers mostly): [DO NOT ROLL OUT YOUR OWN CRYPTO](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=do+not+roll+out). :) And they mean it. Once you've decided to ignore this warning - remember that your crypto is just a toy, so you are free to invent whatever you fancy (it won't be secure anyway).

Comment: `aam 16` which you mention here is not compatible across all 8086 implementations, eg NEC V20/V30.

Comment: @ecm.  Interesting.  [Intel documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam) (unsurprisingly) doesn't list any behaviour differences on old CPUs.  You'd only consider it for code-size reasons anyway.

Comment: [Tiny Encryption Algorithm in x86 assembly](https://www.nayuki.io/page/tiny-encryption-algorithm-in-x86-assembly)