# The values of operands in TEA algorithm will not get decrypted correctly in Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, encryption, x86

I'm writing an assembly project to perform Tiny Encryption algorithm. I followed [the C-Code on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) and transformed it into x86 assembly.

However when I run the algorithm the inputs v0 and v1, they get transformed into gibberish as they should, however, when I try to decrypt the ciphertext, I don't get the original back.

Here is the encryption procedure

```
encrypt PROC
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
xor esi, esi
xor edi, edi
mov ecx, 32
LOOP1:
;sum+= delta
mov eax, sum
ADD eax, delta
mov sum, eax
; (v1 << 4) + k0
mov eax, v1
SAL eax, 4
ADD eax, key0
mov v1l4, eax 
; (v1 + sum)
mov eax, v1
ADD eax, sum
mov v1ps, eax
; (v1 >> 5) + k1
mov eax, v1
SHR eax, 5
add eax, key1
mov v1r5, eax
;((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
mov eax, v1l4
xor eax, v1ps
xor eax, v1r5
; v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
ADD v0, eax
; (v0 << 4) + k2
mov eax, v0
SAL eax, 4
ADD eax, key2
mov v0l4, eax 
; (v0 + sum)
mov eax, v0
ADD eax, sum
mov v0ps, eax
; (v0 >> 5) + k3
mov eax, v0
SHR eax, 5
add eax, key3
mov v0r5, eax
; ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
mov eax, v0l4
xor eax, v0ps
xor eax, v1r5
; v1 += ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
ADD v1, eax

dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
JG LOOP1
ret
encrypt ENDP
```

Here is the decryption procedure

```
decrypt PROC
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
xor esi, esi
xor edi, edi
mov ecx, 32
LOOP2:
; (v0 << 4) + k2
mov eax, v0
SAL eax, 4
ADD eax, key2
mov v0l4, eax 
; (v0 + sum)
mov eax, v0
ADD eax, sum
mov v0ps, eax
; (v0 >> 5) + k3
mov eax, v0
SHR eax, 5
ADD eax, key3
mov v0r5, eax
; ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
mov eax, v0l4
xor eax, v0ps
xor eax, v1r5
; v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
SUB v1, eax

; (v1 << 4) + k0
mov eax, v1
SAL eax, 4
ADD eax, key0
mov v1l4, eax 
; (v1 + sum)
mov eax, v1
ADD eax, sum
mov v1ps, eax
; (v1 >> 5) + k1
mov eax, v1
SHR eax, 5
ADD eax, key1
mov v1r5, eax
; ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
mov eax, v1l4
xor eax, v1ps
xor eax, v1r5
; v0 -= ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
SUB v0, eax
; sum -= delta
mov eax, sum
SUB eax, delta
mov sum, eax

dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
JG LOOP2
ret
decrypt ENDP
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is the decryption not working?

Comment: Try and find a test vector with intermediate values, or create one yourself using a known good implementation. Needless to say, that the output of encryption is gibberish says exactly nothing at all.

Comment: The only known good implementation that I know of is the one on Wikipedia, and I followed it to the letter.

Comment: As @Maarten-reinstateMonica suggests, make your own tests. On encryption, record the values after the last 2 rounds. On decryption, step through each iteration and see where the values diverge. Usually any bugs will become apparent in the first two rounds. You can then zero in on exactly where the differences occur.